# javascript : How to prevent user from entering = in textbox?

Tags: javascript, validation, antisamy

I have a requirement where i have to prevent users from entering `=` in `textbox` in entire application to prevent vulnerability.

```
<input type="text"></input>
```

I have been using `antisamy-1.4.4.xml` and `XSSFilter.java` which takes care of quite a few vulnerability checks but **does not check** for `'='` sign entered in `textbox`. Is there anyway i can do for a textbox that will be done for the entire application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could attach a listener to the `input` elements in the document, check if the user has pressed the `=` key, and if so, take an action.

Something like this should work:

```js
const textInput = document.querySelector('input');
textInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 187) {
     console.log("equals pressed");
        // Prevent default behaviour
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
```

But I wouldn't rely on this as being "secure" since a user can override the JS behavior in their browser. You should still sanitize the input on the server-side.

**Update**

To handle the case where a user **pastes** something into the `input` field, you could intercept the pasted string and strip the illegal characters (equals sign in this case).

Example:

```
textInput.onpaste = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clipboardData = e.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
  textInput.value = pastedData.replace("=", "");
}
```

Or you could just `e.preventDefault()` to disable pasting altogether.

Comment: Sorry, you said textbox so I assumed you meant textarea. I updated my code for input fields.

Comment: This works pretty fine except on one condition where we copy paste = in textbox. +1 for the answer from my side.

Answer (score 0):

On the **frontend**, you can use JavaScript to prevent that:

```js
document.getElementById('text').onkeydown = function(e) {
  const code = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (code === 187) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text">
```

**But** you always need to validate the input on the server-side too!

Comment: But i need to perform the activity for the entire application. Adding this javascript will only help for a particular textbox.

Comment: @sTg Append an `eventListener` to every input field then.

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to add selector class like id or class then you just need to add this js code to your page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#textnote').keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 61) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
       }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the keypress event of the input field and prevent the '=' key.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("text_input").addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
  if(event.which==187 || event.keyCode==187){
event.preventDefault();
}
});
</script>
```